# PayPal address validation to reject non-residential keywords

Tags: php, woocommerce, paypal

I've implemented a snippet to check for non-residential keywords in the address1 and address2 fields in the woocommerce checkout. This returns a message and flags an error, disallowing the payment gateway from proceeding.

Paypal however steams ahead unperturbed.  I see there is some code in Paypal's documentation to action [validation based on the state of a checkbox](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/validation/#synchronous-validation). Is there a simple way to have it instead reference the error output of the existing address validation snippet?  Code in use below for reference.

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'poc_disallow_nonres_shipping' );
  
function poc_disallow_nonres_shipping( $posted ) {
   $address = ( isset( $posted['shipping_address_1'] ) ) ? $posted['shipping_address_1'] : $posted['billing_address_1'];
   $address2 = ( isset( $posted['shipping_address_2'] ) ) ? $posted['shipping_address_2'] : $posted['billing_address_2'];
   $replace = array( " ", ".", "," );
   $address = strtolower( str_replace( $replace, '', $address ) );
   $address2 = strtolower( str_replace( $replace, '', $address2 ) );
   
   $keywords = array("pobox", "dpd", "parcel", "unit", "wizard", "suite", "tnt", "hermes");

   foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
       if ( strstr( $address, $keyword ) || strstr( $address2, keyword ) ) {
      wc_add_notice( 'Sorry, we only ship to residential addresses.', 'error' );
   }
}
}
```

I'm a complete novice, and haven't much idea where to go from here.  Any help much appreciated!